# Java Check if two lists are mutually exclusive

Tags: java

Ok, I have *List a* and *List b*

is there a way to check that no value exist between the two?

```
List a // 1,2,4,5
List B // 1,6,7,8
```

Between both list `// 1    FAILURE`

Comment: `Collections.disjoint(..)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Collections.disjoint(list1, list2)
```

returns `true` if they have no elements in common.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Collections.disjoint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29).

> Returns true if the two specified collections have no elements in
>   common

```
boolean hasCommonElements = Collections.disjoint(listA, listB);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Collections.disjoint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29):

> **public static boolean disjoint(Collection c1, Collection c2):** Returns true if the two specified collections have no elements in common.

**Code:**

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();

System.out.println(Collections.disjoint(a, b));
```

Comment: @Christian what if both list are of different type ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to user `Collections.disjoint(a, b);`
It returns a boolean: true if the lists have no elements in common.